# Get SignalR version programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

I'm trying to get SignalR version in an ASP.NET application. How can I read the currently installed SignalR version programmatically?

Comment: If you have access to the references, you could check the versions of the assemblies.

Comment: Isn't there a way to access the version string directly?

Comment: Trying to find one at the moment, will let you know if I find something. My comment was just a suggestion, because I didn't find one rightaway and this seemed to be a workaround the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
typeof(YourAssemblyName).Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version
```

I have not confirmed my answer, in case it does not work then try

```
typeof(YourAssemblyName).Assembly.GetName().Version
```

Comment: Was just going to post a similar answer. +1 from me

Comment: @Imad I had to revert project to .NET 4.0 from .NET 4.5 and now I'm trying to install SignalR again, just getting errors. I'll let you know when I can run it.

Comment: I've tried the second one as it's simpler and it just worked. One fix, assembly name by itself didn't work (as it's a namespace not a class), so I've just used one of the classes from that assembly (`Hub`, in my example), and it worked correctly.